# MySQL Sorting by substring of a field

Tags: mysql, sorting

A very old DB couldn't be modified, and so instead of adding a "customType" field, the final user "invented" a way to categorize the items. In detail, if the description field:

- starts with a `*` it's of `type1`
- starts with a `#` it's of `type2`
- starts with a `**` it's of `type3`
- otherwise, it's of `type4`

Now, I have been asked to generate some reports sorted by a "category" field but grouped by the type.
Now, APART FROM SPLITTING THE QUERY IN 4 PARTS, and sure enough I can do it, I was wondering if I could do it in a single query.

If there would exist a "customType" field, the query would be stupid easy:

```
SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY customType, category
```

But unfortunately I cannot do it. My first try was something like

```
SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY SUBSTRING(description,2), category
```

But the problem is that I (correctly) get the items grouped by the type together, but the categories are not kept together.
To be more clear, I would like to have an output like

```
aaaaa|cat1
ddddd|cat1
bbbbb|cat2
ccccc|cat2
#aaaa|cat5
#bbbb|cat5
```

But right now I am getting

```
aaaaa|cat1
bbbbb|cat2
ccccc|cat2
ddddd|cat1
#aaaa|cat5
#bbbb|cat5
```

As you can see, the cat1/cat2 are mixed up, the categories should stay together

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of mysql is this and why can't you add the new column?

Comment: It's one of the latest MariaDB but the client running on Windows is already relying on those arbitrary types, and in theory I have no access to the source code of the client - because I should then implement the new field in there too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try ordering by a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM item
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN LEFT(description, 2) = '**' THEN 3
         WHEN LEFT(description, 1) = '*'  THEN 1
         WHEN LEFT(description, 1) = '#'  THEN 2
         ELSE 4 END,
    category;
```

Note that we check for descriptions starting with `**` before checking for starting with `*`.  This is to avoid misclassifying starts with `**` in the same bucket as just starts with `*`.

Comment: I am such a newbie when it comes to MySQL that I didn't even ever SEE the "case when" statement, wow! That's a big one for me :) :) :) Let me try it immediately, thanks!